# Update speed while going to position

Tags: c++, arduino

Need to update potentiometer values all time not only once, try different ways but nothing works :(

I think that main problem is that this function while(digitalRead(gotoPositionAPin)); blocks

Now it's read value and save speed

workflow of code

press button right save position a
press button left save position b
update pot speed (set speed)
update pot acceleration (set accel)
press button go to position A (its going with previous set of speed and acceleration)
press button go to position B (its going with previous set of speed and acceleration)

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Define some steppers and the pins the will use
AccelStepper stepper1(1, 12, 11); 

#define stepsPerRev      1600
#define stepPin          12
#define dirPin           11
#define ledPin           13
#define rotateLeftPin    7
#define rotateRightPin   6
#define savePositionAPin 5
#define savePositionBPin 4
#define gotoPositionAPin 3
#define gotoPositionBPin 2
#define maxSpeedPin      0
#define accelPin         1

// Set this to zero if you don't want debug messages printed
#define printDebug       0

// These are the constants that define the speed associated with the MaxSpeed pot
#define MAX_STEPS_PER_SECOND  1000    // At 200 s/r and 1/8th microstepping, this will be 333 rev/minute
#define MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND  27      // At 200 steps/rev and 1/8th microstepping, this will be 1 rev/minute

// Change this value to scale the acceleration pot's scaling factor
#define ACCEL_RATIO           1

int buttonState = 0;
int stepNumber = 0;
int curSpeed = 100;
int dir = 0;
int maxSpeed = 0;
int accel = 0;
long savedPosA = 0;
long savedPosB = 0;

int loopCtr = 0;
  
float fMaxSpeed = 0.0;
float fStepsPerSecond = 0.0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rotateLeftPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(rotateRightPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(savePositionAPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(savePositionBPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(gotoPositionAPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(gotoPositionBPin, INPUT);
  
  if (printDebug)
  {
    // Initialize the Serial port
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }
  
  // blink the LED:
  blink(2);

  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(800.0);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(600.0);

  // Grab both speed and accel before we start
  maxSpeed = analogRead(maxSpeedPin);
  // Do the math to scale the 0-1023 value (maxSpeed) to 
  // a range of MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND to MAX_STEPS_PER_SECOND
  fMaxSpeed = maxSpeed / 1023.0;
  fStepsPerSecond = MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND + (fMaxSpeed * (MAX_STEPS_PER_SECOND - MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND));
  if (fStepsPerSecond > 1000)
  {
    fStepsPerSecond = 1000;
  }
  accel = analogRead(accelPin)/ACCEL_RATIO;
}

void loop() 
{  
  // First, we need to see if either rotate button is down. They always take precidence.
  if(digitalRead(rotateLeftPin))
  {
    stepper1.setSpeed(-fStepsPerSecond);
    while(digitalRead(rotateLeftPin))
    {
      CheckPots();
      stepper1.runSpeed();
      stepper1.setSpeed(-fStepsPerSecond);
    }
  }
  else if (digitalRead(rotateRightPin))
  {
    stepper1.setSpeed(fStepsPerSecond);
    while(digitalRead(rotateRightPin))
    {
      CheckPots();
      stepper1.runSpeed();
      stepper1.setSpeed(fStepsPerSecond);
    }
  }

  // Go see if we need to update our analog conversions
  CheckPots();
  
  // Check to see if user is trying to save position A or B
  if(digitalRead(savePositionAPin))
  {
    savedPosA = stepper1.currentPosition();
    if (printDebug)
    {
      Serial.print("Saved A at :");
      Serial.println(savedPosA);
    }
    while(digitalRead(savePositionAPin));
  }
  if(digitalRead(savePositionBPin))
  {
    savedPosB = stepper1.currentPosition();
    if (printDebug)
    {
      Serial.print("Saved B at :");
      Serial.println(savedPosB);
    }
    while(digitalRead(savePositionBPin));
  }
    
  // Check to see if the user wants to go to position A or B
  if (digitalRead(gotoPositionAPin))
  {
    if (printDebug)
    {
      // Yup, let's go to position A
      Serial.print("cur pos = ");
      Serial.println(stepper1.currentPosition());
      Serial.print("Going to A = ");
      Serial.println(savedPosA);
      Serial.print("Speed = ");
      Serial.println(fStepsPerSecond);
      Serial.print("Accel = ");
      Serial.println(accel);
    }

    stepper1.setAcceleration(0);
    stepper1.runToNewPosition(stepper1.currentPosition());
    
    stepper1.setMaxSpeed(fStepsPerSecond);
    stepper1.setAcceleration(accel);
    stepper1.runToNewPosition(savedPosA);

    if (printDebug)
    {
      Serial.print("new pos = ");
      Serial.println(stepper1.currentPosition());
    }
    while(digitalRead(gotoPositionAPin));
  }
  else if (digitalRead(gotoPositionBPin))
  {
    // Yup, let's go to position B
    if (printDebug)
    {
      Serial.print("cur pos = ");
      Serial.println(stepper1.currentPosition());
      Serial.print("Going to B = ");
      Serial.println(savedPosB);
      Serial.print("Speed = ");
      Serial.println(fStepsPerSecond);
      Serial.print("Accel = ");
      Serial.println(accel);
    }

    stepper1.setAcceleration(0);
    stepper1.runToNewPosition(stepper1.currentPosition());

    stepper1.setMaxSpeed(fStepsPerSecond);
    stepper1.setAcceleration(accel);
    stepper1.runToNewPosition(savedPosB);

    if (printDebug)
    {
      Serial.print("new pos = ");
      Serial.println(stepper1.currentPosition());
    }
    while(digitalRead(gotoPositionBPin));
  }
}

// Blink the reset LED:
void blink(int howManyTimes) 
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < howManyTimes; i++) 
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
}

void CheckPots(void)
{
  loopCtr++;

  // Only read these once in a while because they take a LONG time
  if (loopCtr == 100)
  {
    maxSpeed = analogRead(maxSpeedPin);

    // Do the math to scale the 0-1023 value (maxSpeed) to 
    // a range of MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND to MAX_STEPS_PER_SECOND
    fMaxSpeed = maxSpeed / 1023.0;
    fStepsPerSecond = MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND + (fMaxSpeed * (MAX_STEPS_PER_SECOND - MIN_STEPS_PER_SECOND));
    if (fStepsPerSecond > 1000)
    {
      fStepsPerSecond = 1000;
    }
  }

  // Read in the acceleration analog value
  // This needs to be scaled too, but to what?
  if (loopCtr >= 200)
  {
    accel = analogRead(accelPin)/ACCEL_RATIO;
    loopCtr = 0;
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to update pot value all the time

Comment: *Need to update potentiometer values all time not only once*. You may need to wrap your `loop` function in an infinite loop (e.g. `for (;;)` or `while (true)`).

Comment: @rturrado This is Arduino code, the two functions `setup()` and `loop()` are treated special there (see https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/basics/BareMinimum).

Comment: @Frodyne Many thanks for the comment. It was just a suggestion but I see it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into "continuous operation" but don't want to introduce *interrupts* into your code (which will have special requirements in and of itself) there are a couple of things you need to get rid of:

1. Endless loops like: `while(digitalRead(savePositionAPin));`
2. System waits like: `delay(200);` as in your `blink()`

and instead use *state variables.*   State variables are more or less what the name says:  variables that hold the *state* of something, so you know what value the button, or timer, or counter had **last time.**

So, instead of a while-loop waiting for a button to be released, just set a **global** or **static** boolean that knows what state you were in the last time `loop()` ran, so you don't trigger the button action again.  You need one boolean flag for each button.

And instead of delays, either create a state variable that holds "passed time" which you can get from `millis()` for example. So don't *wait* but instead you should just check if a certain amount of time has passed so you can toggle the state of the LED.

Adding a blinking LED to `loop()` - (untested example):

```
#define LEDWAIT 300
unsigned long myTime = 0;
bool onoff = false;
loop()
{
    if (myTime == 0)
        myTime = millis();
    
    if ((millis() - myTime) > LEDWAIT) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, onoff ? HIGH : LOW);
        onoff = !onoff;
        myTime = millis();
    }

    // do other things
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not entirely clear to me what your program is supposed to do and what the error is, so please correct me if I am wrong: You want to update a value based on which button is pressed? What is your opinion on using interrupts for triggering the updates?

You may want to edit the formating of your question.

Comment: Value is updatiting till the button is pressed and proces is going, i need to update value all the time